# Spark dataframe filter min(column) failed

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am processing dataframes with the following scala codes in hadoop 3.0.0 and spark 2.2.0. BAQ is a column for IDs and AAA is a string column for date YYMMDD.

```
scala> val dtfAbnoFirs=dtfAbno.filter("AAA>='20201201' and BAQ<>'0'").
     |   groupBy("BAQ").agg("AAA"->"min");
dtfAbnoFirs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [BAQ: string, min(AAA): string]

scala> val dtfBase = dtfCons.select("BAQ","AAA").distinct().filter("BAQ<>'0'").
     |   join(dtfAbnoFirs,Seq("BAQ"),"inner");
dtfBase: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [BAQ: string, AAA: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val dtfBaseEsti=dtfBase.filter("AAA<min(AAA)");
dtfBaseEsti: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [BAQ: string, AAA: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dtfBaseEsti.show(10,false);
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(BAQ#12, 200)
```

It went through with filter("AAA<min(AAA)"), but got errors when I wanted to show data rows after this filter.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(BAQ#12, 200)
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[BAQ#12, AAA#13], functions=[], output=[BAQ#12, AAA#13])
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: min(input[1, string, false])
```

These are some lines of the errors. I recreated the dataframes with AAA as double and got the same error.

Comment: Filtering AAA < min(AAA) must return nothing, because nothing is smaller than the minimum. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: After joining, in the same dataframe dtfBaseEsti, AAA has dates along the whole year, while min(AAA) has dates only in December. Plus, even if it returns nothing, it shouldnt have returned error

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Could you try `"AAA<\`min(AAA)\`"`? The `min` column name needs to be escapted by backticks, otherwise it will be interpreted as the minimum of column AAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min(AAA) in the last statement is a column name, you have to quote it with backticks (`). Spark is trying parse it otherwise

```
scala> val dtfBaseEsti=dtfBase.filter("AAA<`min(AAA)`");
```

Comment: Yep, it worked, but this code worked before. Is it because I compared 'min(AAE) '  with a single value instead of another column? val dfBAQA001AL3 = dfDailAMinMax.filter("min(AAE)<" + douL3.toString());